# JdbcRealm in apache shiro

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

I am new to `apache-shiro`. I tried to implement my `CustomRealm`. But I am getting error.

```java
public class MyCustomRealm extends JDBCRealm {

private Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, Set<String>> roles = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, Set<String>> perm = new HashMap<>();

{
    credentials.put("user", "password");
    credentials.put("user2", "password2");
    credentials.put("user3", "password3");

}

protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo( AuthenticationToken token ) throws AuthenticationException
{

    UsernamePasswordToken uToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;

    if( uToken.getUsername() == null || uToken.getUsername().isEmpty()
            || !credentials.containsKey(uToken.getUsername()) )
    {
        throw new UnknownAccountException("username not found!");
    }

    return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(uToken.getUsername(), credentials.get(uToken.getUsername()), getName());
}
}
```

and my `SecurityManager` implementation is

```java
@Component
public class CustomSecurityManager {
public Subject getSubject()
{
    Realm realm = (Realm) new MyCustomRealm();
    SecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager(realm);
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    return SecurityUtils.getSubject();
}

}
```

But When I run the application, it throws error stating `Cannot cast MyCustomRealm to shiro.Realm`

How can I implement my Custom Realm?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are extending the wrong `JDBCRealm` realm, it should be JdbcRealm` check your import statements.